# Can we check if the web project is working without deployment in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, web

I just started web development, here is a simple example: i write a form submit jsp file and deployment descriptor web.xml to map the logical name used for request and servlet class , and controller servlet handle the http request and use printwriter to print the information in the request.(Don't have the model in this example.)
I know the simple way is to use ant to build a war and put into the web container(Like tomcat), but do i need to do it every time to see if the project is running? Or have a quick way to debug and see the result in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A servlet container is the runtime environment for a Java web application.  There are several open-source servlet containers available.  Tomcat & Jetty are two popular ones.  Both have plugins available that will allow you to do all your development and deployment from within Eclipse:

1. [Tomcat & Eclipse](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-eclipse)
2. [Jetty & Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty#Working_with_Eclipse)